# Validate XML against 2 XSD

Tags: validation, soap, xsd, sax

I'm trying to parse and validate a SOAP request with SAX. Two XSD are necessary, one for SOAP envelope (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) and the one I defined. I cannot find a way to properly validate the request against these two XSD.

Here's the code I use to parse the request and validate it against soapenv.xsd. It works fine. If I specify my XSD instead, the validation fails with "Cannot find the declaration of element 'soapenv:Envelope'".

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(true);

SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();       
saxParser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
saxParser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/xml/soapenv.xsd"));

InputSource is = new InputSource(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/xml/request.xml"));
XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(new MyHandler());
reader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
reader.parse(is);
```

How can I specify a second XSD?

Is there a better way to parse and validate SOAP requests?

**EDIT**

As proposed, I created thirdpty.xsd that imports my two XSDs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="thirdparty:general"
xmlns="thirdparty:general"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="D:\ucfed\ValidateWSDL\src\xml\soapenv.xsd" 
       namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>

    <xs:import schemaLocation="D:\ucfed\ValidateWSDL\src\xml\Presence.xsd" 
       namespace="thirdparty:presence"/>    
</xs:schema>
```

I specify this new XSD for the validation:

```
saxParser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/xml/thidpty.xsd"));
```

But still, only the SOAP envelope XSD is used for validation. If a modify one element from my other XSD, the validation does not detect it.

Here is the xml I am trying to validate

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="thirdparty:presence">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:getPresenceQuery>
            <urn:origAccount uri="test@origin.com"/>
            <urn:destAccount uri="test@destination.com"/>
        </urn:getPresenceQuery>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a driver schema document which imports the other two; validate against the driver.